# getFieldValue or similar in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Is there a way to get the value of a field inside a click handler in formik?

You can use `setFieldValue` in there, so I'd assume (but can't find anywhere) that Formik should have something like that for retrieving values:

```
<Button onClick={() => getFieldValue('name') === 'Test' ? action1 : action2}
```

What is the correct way to do this in Formik?

Answer (score 10):

Formik passes its `values` object into your form via `props`. Imagine you have an input, wired into Formik under the name `firstName`. You can access the input's value via `this.props.values.firstName`:

```js
<button onClick={() => console.log(this.props.values.firstName)}>
  Log firstName
</button>
```

I've test this and verified. It's also demonstrated in several places in [the documentation](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik#the-gist).

Comment: @reectrix Any luck with the above?

Comment: The issue with this is, the value I'm trying to access is deeply nested inside the values array, and also the field name is generated from a combination of attributes because the values I'm working with aren't indexed and don't have a unique identifier, so I wouldn't even be able to find it. So, getting the value from the values array doesn't work for me

Comment: For example, the data I have:  `[{name: Apple, location: US, enabled: true}, {name: Samsung, location: Japan, enabled: false}]`, so my fields are: `appleUSEnabled` and `samsungJapanEnabled`, this is for a group of check boxes. I want to be able to call something like: `getFieldValue('appleUSEnabled')` and get the value immediately, which you can see would be very hard to do by just using the values array, also, computationally, it would be very expensive

Comment: @reectrix Let's [continue this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172259/getfieldvalue-or-similar-in-formik).

Comment: Formik uses the `name` prop to connect the `input` to `values`. If it's in an Array, then your index is just another dot-notation path. You use that same name path to access the data.

First, make sure that you're wired up correctly. I made [this Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o705240v2q) to help. If that doesn't address your problem, then consider building a paths queue/array that accumulates and remembers the full path including index number so that you can access the value later. (We can talk more in the chatroom.)

Comment: Thanks for setting that up, the code looks great. I guess there's really no way to get the field value of another field in there, for instance, if in the click handler, I want to set the current value as checked/unchecked based on another checkbox value, there's no straightforward way to do that.

Comment: I think you can do it if your data is arranged to represent the relationship that you need to check in that component. Maybe you can do one transformation in a `mapStateToProps` style function, and rely on that data shape for this component, and still use the array for other parts of your app. Feel free to tell me the full data relationship you need in the chat, and I'll spend some time thinking about options with you.

Comment: my props doesn't have any "values".

Comment: @schlingel the Formik API has changed a bit since I wrote this. I'll look into updating it. In the meantime, research the keyword `values` in the Formik docs. It's a special concept in their API, along with other things that were in the "Formik Bag" it was once called. Finding `values` is a crucial step in using Formik.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the current Formik values through onChange

```
const [currentValues, setCurrentValues] = useState<UserViewModel>();
...

return (
<>
    <Formik
         initialValues={user}
         onChange={({ nextValues }) => { setCurrentValues(nextValues); }}
    >
    ...
    </Formik>
</>
```

or use a custom React hook

```
import React from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';

const FormSpan = ({ name }) => {
    const [field] = useField(name);
    return (
        <span>{field.value}</span>
    );
};

export default FormSpan;
```

and inside the `Formik`

```
<FormSpan name="preTitle" />
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, but the onChange handler appears to be on Form, not Formik.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the value of field that you initialize in **initalValues** through **props.values** in **Formik**. In your case you want to get the value of name field then you can do as follow:

```
 <Button onClick={() => props.values.name === 'Test' ? action1 : action2}/>
```

or

```
 <Button onPress={() => props.values.name === 'Test' ? action1 : action2}/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.