# How do I access current value of a formik field without submitting?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How do I access value of the `SelectField` named `countryCode` in my React component? Use case is that validation scheme should change according to the countryCode.

```
  <Formik
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => this.onSubmit(values, actions.setFieldError)}
    validationSchema={() => this.registrationValidationSchema()}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={this.props.initialData}
  >
      <Form>
          <Field
            name="countryCode"                                
            component={SelectField}
            label="Country"
            labelClassName="required"
            options={Object.entries(sortedCountryList).map(x => ({
                      value: x[1][1],
                      label: x[1][0]
                    }))}
          />
      </Form>
  </Formik>
```

I have tried to access it via a ref, then via `this.props.values` (as suggested in [getFieldValue or similar in Formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456236/getfieldvalue-or-similar-in-formik)) but both return just undefined or null. My props don't have any "values" field.

EDIT: Found an ugly way: `document.getElementsByName("countryCode")[0].value`. A better way is appreciated.

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64912575/4331722](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64912575/4331722)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can access values like this:

```
<Formik
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => this.onSubmit(values, 
    actions.setFieldError)}
    validationSchema={() => this.registrationValidationSchema()}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={this.props.initialData}
        >
          {({
            setFieldValue,
            setFieldTouched,
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
          }) => (
            <Form className="av-tooltip tooltip-label-right">
              // here you can access to values
              {this.outsideVariable = values.countryCode}
            </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
```

Comment: how do I access the values outside of the scope of form? how can I pass a value of a field to the validationSchema?

Comment: @schlingel I edited answer for accessing value outside of `formik`

Comment: to be honest I don't understand how the "outsideSetValueHandler" achieves my goal. but I found out that I could define an outside variable and add `{this.outsideVariable =  values.countryCode}`. So if you remove that outsidevaluehandler part, I can mark this as a solution.

Comment: @aturan23 i would like to know how to access the values outside of formik

Comment: @MelvinOtieno you can check my latest codes.Just [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60500542/revisions).

Comment: values.countryCode is what I was looking for.  `values`, was passed at alongside `errors`, `touched`... and other params.  Its what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

You can use `ref`, if you need the values outside formik

```
   const ref = useRef(null);
   
   const someFuncton = () => {
       console.log(ref.current.values)
   }
   
   <Formik
       innerRef={ref}
       onSubmit={(values, actions) => this.onSubmit(values,
       actions.setFieldError)}
       validationSchema={() => this.registrationValidationSchema()}
       enableReinitialize={true}
       initialValues={this.props.initialData}
   
   />
       <form></form>
   </Formik>
```

Comment: thanks. this example still works, but there is a better way available now - https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext

Comment: @abhishake Maybe post this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to take the values of each input of the form you can use Formik with the hook useFormik, it is more comfortable since you can separate the form as such:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFormik  } from 'formik';

export const Form = () => {

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
            console.log(values);
        },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('values useEffect: ', formik.values);
    }, [formik.values.name]);

    return (
        <Box>
            <Text>Form</Text>
            <Input
                placeholder="Name"
                value={formik.values.name}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur('name')}
                onChangeText={formik.handleChange('name')}
            />
            <Input
                placeholder="Email"
                value={formik.values.email}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur('email')}
                onChangeText={formik.handleChange('email')}
            />
        </Box>
        
    );

};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it from formik using the Field comp as a wrapper

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Field, FieldProps } from 'formik';
(...other stuffs)

const CustomField = ({
  field,
  form,
  ...props
}) => {
  const currentError = form.errors[field.name];
  const currentField = field.name;  <------ THIS

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    const formattedDate = formatISODate(value);
    form.setFieldValue(field.name, formattedDate, true);
  };

  const handleError = (error: ReactNode) => {
    if (error !== currentError) {
      form.setFieldError(field.name, `${error}`);
    }
  };

  return (
      <TextField
        name={field.name}
        value={field.value}
        variant="outlined"
        helperText={currentError || 'happy helper text here'}
        error={Boolean(currentError)}
        onError={handleError}
        onChange={handleChange}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
        inputProps={{
          'data-testid': `${field.name}-test`, <---- very helpful for testing
        }}
        {...props}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};


export default function FormikTextField({ name, ...props }) {
  return <Field variant="outlined" name={name} component={CustomField} fullWidth {...props} />;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it is very simple just do `console.log(formik.values)` and you will get all the values without submitting it.